# Как определить шрифт, выбранный для текста?

Tags: css, шрифты

На сайте загружены шрифты с разной жирностью для шрифта `Montserrat`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Здесь красным выделены шрифты Montserrat разной жирности]

на последнем рисунке красным выделены шрифты разной жирности для `Montserrat`.
Как определить, какой из них имеет жирность 400 ?
Можно ли как-то быстро определить нужный шрифт в инспекторе кода, кликнув по нужному тексу, в данном случае блок .info-box-title?
Список шрифтов из последнего рисунка:

- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v7/IQHow_FEYlDC4Gzy_m8fcmaVI6zN22yiurzcBKxPjFE.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTUQjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459WxRyS7m0dR9pA.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTUQjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459WxRzS7m0dR9pBOi.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_bZF3g3D_vx3rCubqg.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_bZF3gnD_vx3rCs.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_dJE3g3D_vx3rCubqg.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_dJE3gnD_vx3rCs.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3g3D_vx3rCubqg.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gnD_vx3rCs.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459W1hyyTh89ZNpQ.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459WlhyyTh89Y.woff2

Comment: Загрузите шрифты себе на сайт и подключите. Увеличивая кол-во запросов, вы ничего хорошего не получите.

Comment: @DaemonHK, вы что-то не о том пришете. эти шрифты уже и так загружены на сайт. вопрос не в том, что загружено большое количество шрифтов, вопрос в том, как найти среди этих шрифтов размер жирности 400?

Comment: 1. Как вы их подключаете? Может сервис последовательно это делает с вашим выбором, тогда, скажем, 3 сверху это и есть 400. 2. Попробуйте отключать их и смотреть на изменения. 3. Есть SVG версии шрифтов? Там прописаны идентификаторы

Comment: Заглянуть в CSS файл который вам отдал гугл

Comment: 1) А вам зачем? (может проблема в другом и/или решение проще); 2) Во вкладке "Sources" есть окно просмотра шрифтов